# Windows 7 UAC - Local Administrator and Secpol.msc

Tags: windows, group-policy

I am trying to change my group policy settings temporarily to disable completely UAC. I have local admin rights on my machine, however the UAC options in Secpol.msc are disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a domain computer?

If there is domain policy for these settings, your local policy option will be preconfigured and greyed out.  For example, I've created a domain level policy for UAC auto-elevate.  Below is how the settings appear within `secpol.msc` for a domain joined computer affected by this policy.

[image: secpol.msc]

`secpol.msc` shows the setting from the domain level policy.

[image: option greyed out]

Note that I am unable to alter the policy locally.

You can view which policies, and their settings, are applied to your computer, and user, by running `rsop.msc`.

Comment: Yep its domain joined - is there anyway around this? Trying to amend stuff in Program Files Directory, but cant...

Comment: @diagonalbatman You could remove the computer from the domain... Or get the domain admins to stick your computer in an OU without the offending policy. Not much, supportable, can be done to bypass Group Policy precedence: [LSDOU](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Cool thanks - i will raise a case with IT, looks like a new group policy has been pushed recently